# How to save my certified Ubuntu 11.10 which came with the computer

Tags: 11.10, windows, dual-boot, configuration, re-installation

I have bought a computer with Ubuntu 11.10 and now I need to install Windows XP alonside it. Is it possible to save my certified Ubuntu configuration onto a usb stick, then unistall Ubuntu, install Windows and reinstall Ubuntu?
If so, can you tell me, how to do it? 
Thanks for any hints without using complicated terminology.

Answer (score 2):

View months ago, i used DAR to backup my whole Linux partion. Here is the [tutorial site](http://dar.linux.free.fr/doc/Tutorial.html) and here a [Mini-HowTo](http://dar.linux.free.fr/doc/mini-howto/dar-differential-backup-mini-howto.en.html). After the dar file is created you can save it on a USB-Dongle/HDD.

You can install the [DAR](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dar) [image: Install dar] package with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dar
```

Answer (score 0):

As your Ubuntu root Partition may be ext4, you should use **[fsarchiver](http://www.fsarchiver.org)**.

It's a great commande line tool that will save and compress the content of a partition into an archive file.

When you are done you will be able to restore your archive in a new partition with different size without problem.

I advise you to use it from a liveCD although liveBackup is possible